# Adding AppCompat support library adds old style option menu

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

A have added the appcompat support lib to a project and now suddenly I get the old style option menu at the bottom of the Activities(Button of Shame).  I have minSDK = 16, targetSDK=21, style inhereits Theme.AppCompat, and the Activity extends ActionBarActivity.  I've commented out all code except setting the layout, and I still get the overflow menu button on the bottom from the gingerbread days.  I've tried with version 21 & 19 of the appcompat and get the same result.

Has anyone run into this??

UPDATE:
I used an apk analyzer and the target apk is set to 7.  IDK how this is happening.  I have the targetSDK set to 21 in my build.gradle.

Comment: Are you positive you've defined `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" and android:targetSdkVersion="21" />` directly inside the `<manifest>` tag? Omitting it will default to SDK level 1, which would explain this odd behavior.

Comment: Using gradle & android plugin so actually declaring this in the build.gradle.  But yes, positive.  I have checked about 20x

Comment: Wow, that's very strange indeed. I'm keen to hear more about this.